# How to implement Bootstrap DatePicker (Year/Month) to Django Admin Filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, django-1.11

How do I include an inline bootstrap calendar selector into the Django admin page?

[image]

I was creating a custom form and template from the following: [Django admin add custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620168/django-admin-add-custom-filter)
It works with a text field. I would like to add the calendar to this.

1. How do I include the JS and CSS files for this specific form?
2. How do I pass the value selected to my form?

**YearMonthForm**

```
class YearMonthForm(forms.Form):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.field_name = kwargs.pop('field_name')
            super(YearMonthForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['%s__gte' % self.field_name] = forms.DateField()
```

**YearMonthFilter**

```
class YearMonthFilter(admin.filters.FieldListFilter):
    template = 'maindashboard/filter.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        field_path = kwargs['field_path']
        self.lookup_kwarg_since = '%s__gte' % field_path
        super(YearMonthFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form = YearMonthForm(data=self.used_parameters, field_name=field_path)

    def expected_parameters(self):
        return [self.lookup_kwarg_since]

    # no predefined choices
    def choices(self, cl):
        return []

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.form.is_valid():
            filter_params = {
                p: self.form.cleaned_data.get(p) for p in self.expected_parameters()
                if self.form.cleaned_data.get(p) is not None
            }

            startBillingDate = filter_params["billingDate__gte"]
            year = startBillingDate.year
            month = startBillingDate.month
            day = calendar.monthrange(startBillingDate.year, startBillingDate.month)[1]
            endDate = date(year, month, day)
            filter_params["billingDate__lte"] = endDate

            return queryset.filter(**filter_params)
        else:
            return queryset
```

**filter.html**

```
{% load i18n admin_static %}
<h3>{% blocktrans with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>

{% with choices.0 as i %}

    <label>Filter by Year-Month:</label>
    <div id='InlineMenu'></div>

<form method="GET" action="">
    {{ spec.form.media }}
    {{ spec.form.as_p }}
    <p class="submit-row">
        {# create hidden inputs to preserve values from other filters and search field#}
        {% for k, v in i.get_query.items %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ k }}" value="{{ v }}">
        {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Search" %}">
    <input type="reset" value="{% trans "Clear" %}">
    </p>
</form>

{% endwith %}
```

I'm not sure what the {{ spec.form.media }} tags do. But I've seen in other examples where they add a media function to the form.

**Folder Structure**
Folder Structure:

```
 -projectportal
     - maindashboard
     - templates
         - filter.html
     - static
         - maindashboard
             - css
                 - MonthPicker.min.css
             - js
                 - monthPicker.js
                 - monthPicker.min.js
```

How do I make references to the css and js files for this specific form?

**Update**

Figured out how to reference the JS and CSS files for this form/template.
However, the entire Administration page is styled differently now.
The calendar is now showing up under the admin filters.
Now I need to figure out how to catch the date change events and submit the form.

```
@property
    def media(self):
        return forms.Media(
            css= {'all': ('maindashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'maindashboard/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', 'maindashboard/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css',)},
        js = ('maindashboard/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', 'maindashboard/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'maindashboard/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js', 'maindashboard/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', 'maindashboard/js/monthPicker.js'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The css and js files are referenced from the media method in the YearMonthForm class.
2. Year Month selected is passed after the form submitted in the monthPicker.js file.

   ```
   $("#InlineMenu").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(e){
   // Increase month by 1
   $("#id_billingDate__gte").val(e.date.getFullYear() + "-" + (e.date.getMonth()+1) + "-1");
   $("#billing_calendar").submit();
   ```

   });